# "all of the day" or "all day"

Tags: definite-article, pronouns

The following quotation is from my grammar textbook under a unit about "all" and "whole":

> All day/the whole day = the complete day from beginning to end, for example: 
> *We spent all day/the whole day on the beach*. 
> Note that we say all day (Not all the day), all week (Not all the week) etc.

But to me, "all day" in the above example sounds unnatural. I think it should be replaced with "all of the day" because it is a definite "day" not indefinite:

> We spent all of the day on the beach.

Comment: Did you see the insertion of the preposition **of** in `We spent all of the day on the beach.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All day** is a fixed expression that means the same thing as **the whole day**. Your grammar book is correct.

**All of the day** is grammatical but not idiomatic in the sense of being an established expression. So your example sentence is fine. More often, people might say **We spent all of that day on the beach**, referring back to an occasion that they have already introduced.

Another possibility might be to say: **We spent all of the day and much of the night on the beach**. Here you are using **day** in the sense of the hours of light and not of a 24 hour period, to contrast it with **night**.

Finally, **We spent all day on the beach** says the same thing as **all of the day** in fewer words, and is what most people would say unless they wanted to lay special emphasis on some point.